# Application notice software

Tags: terminology

What is the name where the application shows messages of any updates available whenever the update is available?

Is it called web service?

For example, I have installed an antivirus (avast); sometimes a small popup message shows that an update is available.

I have very vague idea about it, it must be contacting the server periodically for checking the new updates are available or not.

I do not know what the application name is so I was not able to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an auto-update software feature. It's part of the software itself usually - If you'd like to look at some API's regarding implementing them into your application, [find out more here](http://www.sciensoft.com/products/updateshield/updatecheck-api/). [WinSparkle](http://winsparkle.org/) is also something you could look into if your doing Windows development.

Comment: +1 @Daniel thanks for it.  Thought that i would be getting negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

Those are vendor dependant solutions. It is usually *not* a separate software checking for updates. All they do is query a web service that replies with the 'current' version. At least as long as talking about MS-Windows. More elegant and efficient solutions exist in the Linux environment.